# My required and defaultValue attributes are not working on my Textfield, but placeholder is

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I have a simple edit functionality on the card below.

When I click edit, a textfield should appear that allows me to save it.

However, the required and defaultValue attributes are not working on my Textfield, but placeholder is (see image [Textfield Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXzAb.png)).

Saving the edited text isn't a problem (haven't included that code here), just the aspects above.

Any help is much appreciated!!

```
<Card
  style={{
    backgroundColor: `${
      task.isComplete ? "lightgreen" : task.priority ? "lightcyan" : ""
    }`
  }}
>
  {taskEditing === task.id ? (
    <CardHeader
      action={
        <IconButton aria-label="SaveEdits">
          <SaveIcon onClick={() => editTask(task.id)} />
        </IconButton>
      }
      title={
        <TextField
          style={{ width: 410 }}
          required
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(e) => setEditingText(e.target.value)}
          defaultValue='hello'
          placeholder='This is a placeholder'
          value={editingText}
        />
      }
    />
  ) : (
    <CardHeader
      action={
        <IconButton aria-label="Edit">
          <EditIcon onClick={() => setTaskEditing(task.id)} />
        </IconButton>
      }
      title={task.text}
    />
  )}
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized this is a controlled field so I can't use default value. I'd like to get the previous value of the field instead - can anyone help me do that?

Comment: Got an answer separately - I'm meant to use the UseRef hook - see this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69177050/how-do-i-get-the-previous-value-of-a-field-in-react-i-want-to-use-it-to-display

Answer (score 1):

for the required if you set the `label` property, the `*` shown in TextField, and for `defaultValue` if `editingText` equal empty string like `""` TextField show placeholder and when `editingText` equal `null` TextField show your default value.
its look like this:

```
....
const [editingText, setEditingText] = React.useState(null);
...
 <TextField
        required
        label="text"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(e) => setEditingText(e.target.value)}
        defaultValue="hello"
        placeholder="This is a placeholder"
        value={editingText}
  />
```

here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sound-6cg7d?file=/src/App.js:215-277)

Comment: Which one does not work, required, defaultValue or both. is it working on codesandbox? Because it's work for me. Maybe some other code affect to editingText value.

Comment: defaultValue doesn't work because it's a controlled field I think